# Addition of Two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

Let A and B be two positive definite matrices.Then is it true that A+B is also positive definite?
My view:I have taken several examples and every time it indicates that A+B is p.d.But haven't able to prove it explicitly.Anybody please help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true.  Note that for any vector $x \neq 0$, we have
$$
x^T(A + B)x = x^TAx + x^TBx > 0
$$